# Why does an Android phone send out a nameless MAC address in BLE?

Tags: bluetooth

I have 2 Android phones and scan with a BLE scanner (nRF connect) on each phone simultaneously in an isolated area.

In `nRF connect`, both phones display a nameless MAC address, no Bluetooth device name.

I think it's weird nRF connect doesn't show the Bluetooth name of the other phone.

Next, I repeated the same scenario with `Find My Bluetooth Device` app (FMBD) on both phones. The older phone shows a nameless MAC AND the device name, while the new phone only showed a nameless MAC address.

Conversely, when I repeat this scenario with the native Android Bluetooth scanners, I simply see their device names, no MAC addresses whatsoever.
Note, both phones have 'Show nameless Bluetooth devices' enabled in developer options, yet no MAC addresses in the native BT scanners.

What is causing the nameless MAC addresses I see in `nRF connect` and in `FMBD` on the old phone, in my Bluetooth scans?